# How do I remove the vertical padding in a div table-cell?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Take this [web example](http://snook.ca/technical/div_tables/fluid3col.html) into account (it seems to have the same issue) I have the following CSS on [my website](http://lawtonsoft.com/) (note the space between the `#head` and `#body` `<div>'s`):

```
#body {
        display: table;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
}

#body-row {
        display: table-row;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

.column-left, .column, .column-right {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 0px;
        border: dotted 2px #89E;
}

.column-left, .column-right {
        width: 190px;
        font-size: .95em;
}
```

However, this still adds a space between the very top and bottom of the table-cell. Padding and margin do no seem to do anything for this. Advice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
.column-left, .column, .column-right {
    vertical-align: top; /* add vertical align top to fix this issue */
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0px;
    border: dotted 2px #89E;
}
```

Comment: Duh-of course! I was wondering about that earlier if that would be needed, but it never made itself apparent (until now). Thanks! That's the answer.

Comment: Well, aligning to the top moves the padding to the bottom rather than removing it.

Comment: What if he wants vertical-align: middle?